# Get last record for each bonus type by X player from table A grouped by an field of table B

Tags: mysql, max

As the title says, i want to get the last record of each **bonus_id** by X player from table **"redeemed_bonuses"** grouped by **name** field from table **bonuses**.

It's my database structure:

Table: **bonuses**

```
"id"    "uid"               "name"              "free_spins"        
--------------------------------------------------------
"1"     "1111111111111"     "welcome_bonus"     "0"
"2"     "1111111111112"     "deposit100_bonus"  "0"
"3"     "1111111111113"     "deposit150_bonus"  "0"
"4"     "1111111111114"     "deposit200_bonus"  "0"
"5"     "1111111111111"     "welcome_bonus"     "10"
"6"     "1111111111112"     "deposit100_bonus"  "10"
"7"     "1111111111114"     "deposit200_bonus"  "10"
"8"     "1111111111112"     "deposit100_bonus"  "50"
```

Table: **players**

```
"id"    "username"
------------------
"1"     "pepe"
"2"     "pedro"
"27"    "david"
"28"    "jorge"
```

Table: **redeemed_bonuses**

```
"id"    "player_id"     "bonus_id"      "instance_id"
-----------------------------------------------------
"1"     "1"             "7"             "abcd456"
"2"     "28"            "1"             "abc2356"
"3"     "2"             "7"             "ghb564"
"4"     "27"            "1"             "dfv444"
"5"     "27"            "6"             "vbb333"
"6"     "27"            "8"             "vd4332"
```

Desired result for **player_id 27**:

```
"id"    "player_id"     "bonus_id"      "instance_id"   "bonuses.name"
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
"4"     "27"            "1"             "dfv444"        "welcome_bonus"
"6"     "27"            "8"             "vd4332"        "deposit100_bonus"
```

[**DB-FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qRJDSTTQAvkohRw2uPnozv/25)

**Aditional Info:** I was looking the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/2363860) but both are not my case.

Comment: Well done for providing a fiddle but the linked answer exactly addresses your needs

Comment: Thanks for response but i already tried that and does not give me the expected result. If you want, i can refresh db fiddle with that query and you will see.

Comment: @Strawberry i have updated db fiddle with the query of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/2363860 but the result is not the expected because i have 2 other tables for get the max id and not the same table.

Comment: Your data set is not representative of the problem, or your description of the problem is inadequate.

Comment: Description edited. In all I do not know why the data is not representative if I have put what I want to obtain clearly.

Comment: Also, your naming convention makes it really hard to figure out which column relates to which.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry you are right. I have updated all the tables name of post and the db fiddle too. I think now it is clear.

Comment: I would say this is less clear :-( Perhaps it's personal preference, but I hate using `id` as a column name. If it's a `bonus_id`, call it a `bonus_id` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer; I don't know where you get id 4 and 6 from...

```
 SELECT a.*
      , c.instance_id
   FROM bonus_records a
   JOIN
      (
      SELECT uid
           , player_id
           , MAX(x.id) bonus_id
        FROM bonus_records x
        JOIN redeemed_bonus_records y
          ON y.bonus_id = x.id
       WHERE y.player_id = 27
       GROUP
          BY uid
           , player_id
     ) b
    ON b.bonus_id = a.id
  JOIN redeemed_bonus_records c
    ON c.bonus_id = a.id
   AND c.player_id = b.player_id;
  +----+-----+------------------+------------+-------------+
  | id | uid | name             | free_spins | instance_id |
  +----+-----+------------------+------------+-------------+
  |  1 | 11  | welcome_bonus    |          0 | dfv444      |
  |  8 | 12  | deposit100_bonus |         50 | vd4332      |
  +----+-----+------------------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Try to add more columns like instance_id and compare. You will see that although it returns the max id, but the rest of the columns do not belong to the max id row

Comment: That's where the linked answer comes in.

Comment: I will try to explain to you in the best possible way. The bonus_records table contains different bonuses that are grouped by their name or uid, that is, all those rows that have the same name, that is, they are different versions of the same bonus. So I want to get the last row for each type of bonus (grouped by bonus_records.name) of the table redeemed_bonus_records that correspond to player 27

Comment: Your query still does not work and to check, if you add instance_id, you'll see that it keeps returning the rows of bonus_id = 6

Comment: My query returns ids 1 and 8, so if you join redeemed_bonuses to above on bonus_id = id, you will get the right rows !?!

Comment: After this last update, yes, it works perfectly! Thank you!